# Resources for Logo Design Trademarking

Tags: legal, trademark

What is the best way to provide trademarking information on a logo to a client after you have delivered their new logo design?

Comment: Is this a new logo? A logo is not automatically trademarked, someone  has to file for it. At least they do in the US.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean a [**brand style guide**](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/79443/when-to-create-a-brand-style-guide)?

Answer (score 1):

In the US, you can go to the Patent and Trademark Office:

> https://www.uspto.gov/trademark

2 things in particular are useful:

1. The trademark search - horrid interface, but lets you find which names and logos might be similar. Used this a lot when searching for name.
2. Application = self explanitory. Haven't done gone through this process. I'd recommend at least talking to a lawyer if not having her handle the whole application.

Answer (score 1):

You could either point them to the place where they need to file for it (depending on your country of origin) or to a lawyer that specializes in trademark.

In Canada, you will need to go through the Canadian Intellectual Property Office (CIPO)

https://www.canada.ca/en/services/business/ip/trademarks.html